# Parsing a string character by character in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to parse a string character by character. I am using perl to do that. Is there any way where we can start from the first character of the string and then loop character by character. Right now I have split the string into an array and I am loo[ping through the array.

```
$var="junk shit here. fkuc lkasjdfie.";
@chars=split("",$var);
```

But instead of spliting the wholes string before itself, is there any descriptor which would point to the first character of the string and then traverse each character? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: With Perl, there is generally a [better] way of solving a problem without traversing/parsing strings yourself. What is your real goal?

Comment: @perreal: My main goal is to split a given string (a large one) into sentences. Splitting using ".", "?". But there are again more constraints like "Dr. W. Fletcher" should not split into a 3 sentences just because there are 3 occurences of "." (fullstop). It is still a single sentence

Comment: And how will you know if the current . is one that marks end of sentence or if it is part of a sentence?

Comment: @Ashwin, sounds like you can use a regex split with look-around assertions.

Comment: @szabgab  :That is the problem I am trying to solve. As soon as a fullstop is encountered, it has to be matched with the previous characters to determine if they were initials, titles etc

Comment: Well, do you have a set of strings that you will recognize as initials, titles etc.? If yes, you can build a regex using those that will match (or not match) and this will split (or not split). Probably using negative look-around features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be the skeleton of the script/regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $str = "The story of Dr. W. Fletcher who is a dentist. The hero of the community.";

my @sentences = split /(?<!(Dr| \w))\./, $str;
print Dumper \@sentences;
```

And the output is:

```
$VAR1 = [
      'The story of Dr. W. Fletcher who is a dentist',
      undef,
      ' The hero of the community'
    ];
```

Comment: What is the "<" symbol signify after "?" ?

Comment: (?<! ... ) is a negative look-behind. Search https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlre.pod for 'look-behind'

Answer (score 3):

```
my $var = "junk sit here. fkuc lkasjdfie.";

while ($var =~ /(.)/sg) {
   my $char = $1;
   # do something with $char 
}
```

or

```
for my $i (1 .. length $var) {
  my $char = substr($var, $i-1, 1);
}
```

and when bench-marked, `substr` method is better performing than `while`,

```
use Benchmark qw( cmpthese ) ;
my $var = "junk sit here. fkuc lkasjdfie." x1000;

cmpthese( -5, {
    "while" => sub{
      while ($var =~ /(.)/sg) {
         my $char = $1;
         # do something with $char 
      }
    },
    "substr" => sub{
      for my $i (1 .. length $var) {
        my $char = substr($var, $i-1, 1);
      }
    },
});
```

result

```
         Rate  while substr
while  56.3/s     --   -53%
substr  121/s   114%     --
```

Comment: How does the first method work? And would using regex be faster than that the second method

Comment: @Ashwin check http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#More-matching To be sure about speed, benchmark is required http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's faster than splitting it but you can make a copy, [reverse](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) it and the [chop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html) it until it's empty.

```
$a = "dude"; 
$b = reverse($a); 
for ($i = length($b) ; $i>0 ; $i--) {
  print chop $b; print "\n";'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Uses less memory than split, faster than "while ( $text =~ /(.)/sg ) { ... }":

```
my $text = 'Ö' x 10000;  # encoded
if ( open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', \$text ) {
    while ( read $fh, my $chr, 1 ) {
        my $enc = $chr;  # decoded
        utf8::encode($enc) if utf8::is_utf8($enc);
        print $enc, ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't reading a character here: you are reading an octet.

Comment: Brian you are right, code corrected, now reads by character.